# Full word match with grepl

Tags: r

I would like to have TRUE FALSE instead of the following. Any suggestion?

```
testLines <- c("buried","medium-buried")
grepl('\\<buried\\>',testLines)
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: `testLines == "buried"`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```
testLines <- c("buried","medium-buried")
grepl('^buried$',testLines)

#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

My understanding (and regex is not my forte) is that `^` denotes the start of the string and `$` the end.

Comment: working! thanks so much. Would you like to explain your solution? Would be great to understand.

Comment: @SumaiyaIqbal I've added an explanation to my answer.